# Button function called twice after DatePicker change

Tags: javascript, jquery, sapui5, alert, v8

If I manually enter a date into a `sap.m.DatePicker` (typing it not using the value help picker) and press a button straight away without losing focus on the field, the button doesn't do anything which is correct, but when I click it again the press function is called twice.

It seems like the change event is called when I click over the button, so the button isn't pressed, but when I then press the button again it fires twice.

https://jsfiddle.net/saznxrs6/

> ```
> onDateChange: function(){
>     alert("date changed");
> },
> onSubmit: function(){
>     alert("Hello!");
> }
> ```

Enter a date into the picker manually i.e. 01/12/2017, then click the submit button without losing focus on the date field first. You should see an alert for the date changed. Click the button again, you should get two alerts for the button function.

Is this a UI5 bug or something I am doing wrong?

Comment: As the issue is [reproducible only with `alert`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62137399/5846045), I'm voting to close this question.

Comment: The issue is no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like a Bug in Chrome. Firefox do it all fine. 
 - set value in timepicker
 - press button

-> focus of timepicker is lost so the change-event is fired and a popup appears.
-> button is pressed so the click event is also fired and a second popup appears

I dont know why it doesn't work in chrome. There the second popup is missing and it comes up after pressing the button again.

Comment: even in safari browser it working the same way mentioned by @pyro

Answer (score 0):

The issue is reproducible only with `alert()` which ...

- ... is handled differently depending on the browser.
- ... UI5 apps shouldn't deal with in the production environment.

Replace `alert` with `console.log` and you can see that the handlers are executed as expected:

1. <kbd>Press</kbd>: "date changed", "hello"
2. <kbd>Press</kbd>: "hello"